# Nested LinearLayout widget design with different weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have been trying for ages to get the following layout to work for a widget and being inexperienced with layouts it is cause me some grief, at first I had relative layout but it doesn't seem to re-size itself according to phone size and text input.

As you can see below is the layout I want. Boxes 1 to 11. I assume a LinearLayout is the best layout? All the boxes will contain text. Bozes 2, 3 and 4 are half the height of box 1 and boxes 5 and 6 are also half of 1 (sorry it's a bit of a rubbish quick design).

Boxes 8 and 9 are half each of 7 in height so weight wise (as far as I understand) will be 1 each of 7. 7 is half the length and 8 + 9 are the other half (length wise).

10 and 11 are half the width each of width.

Do you think the GridLayout will be better for this bearing in mind that the widths of the boxes can expand or contract by a few digits, for example, if someone selects Fahrenheit instead of Celsius, 100 degrees Fahrenheit will have an extra digit compared to 37 degrees Celsius, or 32 degrees Fahrenheit will be 0 degrees Celsius. Or 200mm of rain to inches will be 8in (shrunk by 2 digits).

[image: Layout Design]

Comment: you can achieve it using weight property of linear layout easily rather than going with grid layout .first of all you have to clear your design pattern .

Comment: GridLayout should be the best choice.

Comment: I will try GridLayout and LinerLayout and see the difference.

Comment: use linear layout and use weight attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the code bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#e3e2ad">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:background="#aacaff" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:background="#bcf5b1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="6" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/dim_foreground_disabled_material_dark">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="7" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="8"
                android:background="#e3e2ad" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="9" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary_material_light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:background="#bcf5b1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="11" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

I used `Textview` for showing numbers. You can use anything instead.
If you have any query, please ask. Also, if you use `wrap_content` at correct place, the part of layout will expand accordingly.

Comment: I can only check this in 5 hours time. But yes that is what am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, but I would make root a `RelativeLayout` and group elements in `LinearLayout` (numbers 2,3,4 is one layout, 5,6 - second and so on). So every `LinearLayout` you can easily manage with attributes `layout_below`, `layout_parentBottom` etcetera.
See all of attributes for children of `RelativeLayout` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).
I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes this does help me a bit. Apologies about the broad question. I just want to see the different ways if doing this. It will help me understand layouts.

Comment: @Dino, that's fine, just pick the best solution as for you, because you know, there are many many ways to do this and hard to say 100% what is the best or most efficient way to do that.

Comment: yes Yurets is right . Make use of both RelativeLayouts and Linearlayouts to achieve above layout. It would be difficult with grid layout